# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined on react BeatifulDnD

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use React hooks with atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd
https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd

Looks reorder function inside list is working properly. But there are something wrong with provider part.

When I drag Draggable items it goes TypeError

I'm pretty much stuck in here.

[image]

```js
import React from 'react';
import { DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
const reorder = (list, startIndex, endIndex) =>
{
    const result = Array.from(list);

    const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1);
    result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed);
    return result;
};
export default function GoogleAnalyticsScreen()
{
    {
        const [state, setState] = React.useState(
            {
                items: ["1", "2", "3"],
                selected: ["4", "5"]
            }
        );
        const onDragEnd = result =>
        {
            const { source, destination } = result;
            if (!result.destination)
            {
                return;
            }
            const state = reorder(
                source.droppableId,
                source.index,
                destination.index
            );
            setState(state);
        }
        return (
            <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
                <Droppable droppableId="droppable" type="DraggableItem" key="list">
                    {(_fromProvided, _fromSnapshot) => (
                        <div
                            ref={_fromProvided.innerRef}
                            {..._fromProvided.draggableProps}
                            {..._fromProvided.dragHandleProps}
                        >
                            {state.items.map((fromItem, fromIndex) => (
                                <Draggable draggableId={"drag-" + fromIndex} index={fromIndex} key={fromIndex}>
                                    {(provided, snapshot) => (
                                        <div
                                            ref={provided.innerRef}
                                            {...provided.draggableProps}
                                            {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                                        >drag me</div>
                                    )}
                                </Draggable>
                            ))}
                            {_fromProvided.placeholder}
                        </div>
                    )}
                </Droppable>
            </DragDropContext>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got fixed this issue by my self.
line#32

```
setState(state);
```

supporse to be.

```
setState({items:state});
```

it was pretty dumb mistake.